# How do I extract and push text from promise all strings to map or array?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I was trying to extract the chrome extensions id and I was able to get the Ids of the loaded chrome extensions.

```
        browserPage = await browserContext.newPage();
        await browserPage.goto("chrome://extensions");
        await browserPage.locator('text=Developer mode This setting is managed by your administrator. >> #knob').click();
```

Working Code: It is printing the IDs into the console.

```
await browserPage.locator('#extension-id').allTextContents().then(id => {
            console.log(id);
        });
```

Output:

```
[
  'ID: kjkkkbelkplchpnbmhlmcbfmgjbkdpkj',
  'ID: cciedebhmaekejckbbnjedloddbkfbpd'
]
```

I don't know how to extract the Ids into a map or array.

Solutions tried:

```
const ids: never[] = []
        await browserPage.locator('#extension-id').allTextContents().then(id => {
            ids.push(id);
        });
```

**Error: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.**

Comment: Did you try changing the type to `string[]` instead of `never[]`?

Comment: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.

```js
let ids: string[] = [];
await browserPage
  .locator('#extension-id')
  .allTextContents()
  .then((arrStr) => {
    arrStr.forEach((ele) => {
      ids.push(ele.substring(4));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

`allTextContents` returns a `Promise<string[]>`, so you only need to assign it to the variable:

```
const ids = await browserPage.locator('#extension-id').allTextContents();
```

Then `ids` will be inferred to be the type `string[]` for you.